# Running two JavaScript functions exclusively on the same div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a class name to render a partial when an ajax request is made.
This is what the div looks like

```
<div class="main-section">

  {% partial "product-list"%}

</div>
```

Now i separated the functions this way to update the div using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Pagination part
    $('.main-section').on('click', '.pagination > li > a', function (event) {
    var page = $(this).text();
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
        $.request('onNav', {
            data: {page: page},

        });
    }
});
</script>





<script type="text/javascript">

//Pagination part
    $('main-section').on('click', '.pagination > li > a', function (event) {
    var page = $(this).text();
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
        $.request('onFilterProduct', {
            data: {page: page},

        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Now there seem to be some conflict. it works but sometimes displays the pagination results of the function that was not clicked. Is there a way to combine the two function and only ensure just one runs when clicked without conflict?

Comment: Other than the second snippet have a selector of `main-section` (which is not a tag) and the other having `.main-section`, *these two snippets look identical?*  Edit: Nvm, the option given to `$.request` is different.

Comment: Do you really need the two snippets?  Could you not just do both `$.request` calls in a single snippet?

Comment: Also where does `$.request` come from?  I don't see that listed on the API.

Comment: What determines whether it should be passing 'onNav' or 'onFilterProduct'?  And I guess I'm assuming $.request is somehow an extension to one of the jQuery ajax functions, what are you doing with the results?